# Token: Plus operator removed from access token

Tags: c#, string, api, token

I have created a URL with Access Token. When I open the URL, the + operator get removed with whitespace from the token at backend end-points. Can someone help me to know why this happening? Below is my URL with the token.

```
api/meeting?token=wf+hbRFOp/fI5jSsZ0KT9K7lkvZSJLUHyc8yy6TI9HE2HdEx0WXAqWxEUjQL/6vX
```

At controller level, token is recieved as `wf hbRFOp/fI5jSsZ0KT9K7lkvZSJLUHyc8yy6TI9HE2HdEx0WXAqWxEUjQL/6vX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I open the URL, the + operator get removed with white-space from the token at backend end-points.

Yes, that's because in URLs, `+` is the used to represent a space. I suspect your token is actually a base64-encoded value - you should use a URL-safe base64 decodabet instead of just putting the regular base64 value directly into the query. If you *must* use the regular base64 one, you need to escape the `+` character as `%2B`. I'd suggest using [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-6.0#system-web-httputility-urlencode(system-string)) to do that.